# Elementwise Matrix Function "factorization"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, numerical-methods

I have a vector V of length n that results from matrix A being applied to vector X, 
A is known, how would one find two new matrices K and L of lengths m and (n-m), such that V is still the same result forall vectors X (or just one is fine if forall is too intractable) , where first m elements of V are determined by the first m elements of X multiplied by K and the rest (n-m) elements of V similarly determined by L times rest of X. Iterative methods are acceptable. Any help appreciated.

Comment: It seems you want some decomposition of $A$ into $K$ and $L$, e.g. $A = K L$ or $A = K + L$. Can you be more specific? And what do you mean by a matrix of "length $m$ and $n -m$? Not a matrix with $m$ rows and $n-m$ columns?

Comment: no, because what we have is V = AX, |V| = n, now i want to break A into K and L, but not simple decomposition, because that would only apply if dimensions of K, L and A were the same, i want to apply K to the first half of the elements of X, and L to the other, such that V=AX, but also V_1 = KX, and V_2 = LX, im aiming for general case though, not just 2 element variant

Comment: Then $K$ consists simply of the upper $m$ rows of $A$ and $L$ of the ofher rows, or?

Comment: K is entirely unknown, that's what I want to solve for 

V = [v1,v2,v3, v4] = AX , [v1, v2] = KX, [v3,v4] = LX, non linear algebra analogue would be f(a,b) = g(f(a), f(b)) but thats probably a bad example because the length's are all convenient in the calculus one. I need to obtain same V but as combination of subproblems with smaller dimensions, hence needing to compartmentalize the elements.

Comment: $A$ does compute $V$ by using all components of $X$. You are not looking for a $K$ which gives the upper half of $V$ but only uses some components of $X$?

Comment: no I'm looking for a K that gives upper half of V given all of X, the matrix isn't square.

Comment: $K$ is simply the first $m$ rows of $A$, and $L$ the remaining, just as @mvw said.

Comment: so you can really just divide the set into two sets and dot product them on each part of the split output set? huh, thought they'd be some rider that would prevent that, not used to dividing a problem into subproblems being that simple D:. Thank you so much Wong and mvw.